# R: Transform large matrix to dataframe format where values of 1 row must become different rows of 1 column

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, transform

In this example dataframe we have clients as row indices and products as columns, the values are the quantities bought. 
[Example in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhdSQ.png)

We now want to change this matrix to a dataframe with 3 columns: klantnr, product & quantity, like this:
[Example in Excel of desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuX4Y.png)

How can this be done in R?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try `library(reshape2); melt(df)`

Comment: Try `pivot_longer` from `dplyr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(Klatnrs = 1:4, ProductA = c(5, 9, 8, 7), ProductB = c(4, 10, 4, 8),
                 ProductC = c(6, 7, 3, 2), ProductD = c(2, 3, 3, 2))

df 
#>   Klatnrs ProductA ProductB ProductC ProductD
#> 1       1        5        4        6        2
#> 2       2        9       10        7        3
#> 3       3        8        4        3        3
#> 4       4        7        8        2        2

df %>% pivot_longer(2:5) %>% select(Klatnrs, Product = name, Price = value)
#> # A tibble: 16 x 3
#>    Klatnrs Product  Price
#>      <int> <chr>    <dbl>
#>  1       1 ProductA     5
#>  2       1 ProductB     4
#>  3       1 ProductC     6
#>  4       1 ProductD     2
#>  5       2 ProductA     9
#>  6       2 ProductB    10
#>  7       2 ProductC     7
#>  8       2 ProductD     3
#>  9       3 ProductA     8
#> 10       3 ProductB     4
#> 11       3 ProductC     3
#> 12       3 ProductD     3
#> 13       4 ProductA     7
#> 14       4 ProductB     8
#> 15       4 ProductC     2
#> 16       4 ProductD     2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, in the actual dataframe I have 254 products and 63657 clients, but format is exactly the same so I tried your code:

df %>% pivot_longer(2:255) %>% select(Klatnrs, Product = name, Price = value)

However, I receive this error:
Error in select(., klantnr, product = name, price = value) : 
  unused arguments (klantnr, product = name, price = value)

Comment: @JoraSteenackers try specifying `dplyr::select(Klatnrs, Product = name, Price = value)`. You could also remove the `select` statement and choose the appropriate columns by hand.